# Pandas Replace Null With Column Name

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data frame:
import pandas as pd

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[np.nan,5,6]})
d
    a   b
0   1   NaN
1   2   5.0
2   3   6.0
```

For any column where a value is 'NaN', I'd like to replace that value with the column name. My real data has many columns.

Desired result:

```
    a   b
0   1   b
1   2   5.0
2   3   6.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [60]: d.fillna(d.columns.to_series())
Out[60]:
   a  b
0  1  b
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Comment: Thanks, will mark as correct once I can. As a follow-up, what if I wanted to instead fill any non-null value with the column name?

Comment: @DanceParty2, that's an nteresting question! Let me try to find a solution for it...

Comment: Sure. I'll post as a separate question and share the link.

Comment: Thanks. I've posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825048/pandas-replace-not-null-with-column-name

Comment: @DanceParty2, you've got already [a very neat and elegant answer from root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45825140/5741205) ;-)