# Replacing non-null values with column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[np.nan,5,6]})
d
    a   b
0   1   NaN
1   2   5.0
2   3   6.0
```

I would like to replace all non-null values with the column name.

Desired result:

```
    a   b
0   a   NaN
1   a   b
2   a   b
```

In reality, I have many columns.

Thanks in advance!

**Update to answer from root:**
To perform this on a subset of columns:

```
d.loc[:,d.columns[3:]] = np.where(d.loc[:,d.columns[3:]].notnull(), d.loc[:,d.columns[3:]].columns, d.loc[:,d.columns[3:]])
```

Comment: No need for `loc` if you want to use my method for a subset.  See my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of one possibility using `apply/transform`:

```
In [1610]: d.transform(lambda x: np.where(x.isnull(), x, x.name))
Out[1610]: 
   a    b
0  a  nan
1  a    b
2  a    b
```

You could also use `df.where`:

```
In [1627]: d.where(d.isnull(), d.columns.values.repeat(len(d)).reshape(d.shape))
Out[1627]: 
   a    b
0  a  NaN
1  a    b
2  b    b
```

Comment: Both great answers and difficult to choose. By the way, what if I need to do this with a subset of columns?

Comment: @DanceParty2 You can use `df.loc` for slice based indexing, and perform the operation on the slice.

Comment: Hi @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ what is the different between `d.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.isnull(),x,x.name))` and transform :)

Comment: @Wen I think `df.transform` is vectorised...? Not 100% sure. I know `apply` is slow.

Comment: @COLDSPEED will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html):

```
d[:] = np.where(d.notnull(), d.columns, d)
```

The resulting output:

```
   a    b
0  a  NaN
1  a    b
2  a    b
```

**Edit**

To select specific columns:

```
cols = d.columns[3:]  # or whatever Index/list-like of column names
d[cols] = np.where(d[cols].notnull(), cols, d[cols])
```